# Understanding shutdown requested flag when shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I'm reading B. Goetz JCIP and come across some misunderstanding in the section 7.2 about cancellin Thread-based services. Here's the code:

```
public class LogWriter{

    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private final LoggerThread logger;

public LogWriter(Writer writer){
    this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(CAPACITY);
    this.logger = new LoggerThread(writer);
}

public void start(){ logger.start(); }

public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
    queue.put(msg);
} 

private class LoggerThread extends Thread {
    private final PrintWriter writer;
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true)
               writer.println(queue.take());
        } catch(InterruptedException ignored){
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
     }
}
```

He said that such service does not provide a way to terminate it. He gives another alternative to it:

```
public void log(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
     if(!shutdownRequested)
           queue.put(msg);
     else
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("logger is shut down");
 }
```

Now he says that

> The implementation of log is chek-than-act sequnce: producers could
>   observe that the service has not yet been shut down but still queue
>   messages after the shutdown, again **with the risk that the producer**
>   **might get blocked in log and never become unlocked**.

The emphasized is not clear to me.

If the consumer drained the queue to some collection it will make any producers blocked in `log()` unlocked. Even if some producer try to put a log message to the queue, it won't be blocked. The only thing that I see is this message won't be logged since the queue has been drained.

***QUESTION:*** Why does he says that producers mught be blocked and never unlocked. What did I miss?

Comment: Can you post the full code? Is `shutdownRequested` used only in `log` method, or also in the logger thread?

Comment: @Joni That's the full one. He didn't provide more details.

Comment: @Joni logger thread is an inner class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `BlockingQueue` doc you can see:

> A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue
>   to become non-empty when retrieving an element, **and wait for space to
>   become available in the queue when storing an element**.

I.e. producer may be blocked if there is no more space left in the queue: if the service has been shut down the queue is not drained anymore.

Comment: But when shutdown is requested we just set the flag to `true` and then the consumer drain the queue. So, all logger wainting in `log()` is getting unlocked. The only can happen is that the number of threads greater than queue capacity reproduce such race conditions....

Comment: I agree, this should be possible only for the case of many threads and samll capacity. But still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is incomplete it's hard to say what the author intended. Presumably the logger thread also checks `shutdownRequested` to stop logging:

```
public void run() {
    try{
        while(shutdownRequested)
           writer.println(queue.take());
    } catch(InterruptedException ignored){
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
 }
```

If you write this, consider a scenario where the shutdown is requested when the queue is full and there are threads blocked on `queue.put`: the logger thread stops calling `queue.take` and these threads stay blocked forever.

Even if that was not the case, there is a race condition with the variable `shutdownRequested`. A thread may request shutdown between the variable is read and the message is queued in the `log` method, so that messages still get queued after shutdown was requested.